# How design restful api for sending email to users

Tags: rest

Sending email including new password to user is provided by rest api.

for example, after call "user/{email}", user will receive the email to get new password.

I think sending email is not kind of GET, PUT, POST, PUT.

How design url to more perfect restful api.

Comment: Please stop using the [tag:restful-url] tag. [It's such a misconception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376362/1426227).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think sending email is not kind of GET, PUT, POST, PUT.

That's true, but that's not what you are doing.  You are sending a *document* to the server to advance a protocol, that has a side effect of sending an email.  See [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)

> HTTP is an application protocol whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network.

For the case of performing a password reset, you probably want clients to recognize that the operation is not [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1).  So you should prefer POST or PUT to GET.

On the web, where we are using HTML representations of resources, POST is the only option available to us, and it works just *fine*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of missing information here but have a look at Send Grid's API. I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I cannot leave comments.